# Avoid z-index working relative to the parent element

Tags: css, z-index

I come with a question about an odd behavior regarding the z-index property. The situation in terms or layers is the following:

```
div#wrapper
    div#sidebar (fixed position and 5 as z-index)
        div#pop-up (absolute position and 15 as z-index)
div#black-layer (fixed position and 10 as z-index)
```

The thing then is that I want to have a semi-transparent black layer over everything, with the next exception: over it I want another arbitrary div (depending on the case). A bit like the typical light-box.

What's happening now is that the pop-up, which is supposed to be over the black-layer, since their z-index is higher, is actually under it.

My conclusion after several tries is that the reason this occurs like so is because #pop-up is a child of #sidebar. Indeed, if I put it outside, it works as I pretend. Like:

```
div#wrapper
    div#sidebar
    div#pop-up
div#black-layer
```

But this is not a good solution at all. First because it is not semantically correct from the point of view of the HTML. And also because I have the necessity of having more "pop-ups" in other parts of the code and is not a good idea split the logic this way by keeping separately all of them.

Thank you in advance.

**Update:** It is even more strange now. I haven't changed anything, but just made a test in Firefox instead of Chrome, and it works there as I expected, so the pop-up is in fact over the black-layer. And also in Opera. And it does not work in Maxthon. Just as a note, I'm using Linux.

Comment: The way this is typically handled is that when the pop-up is shown, it's content is moved (or copied) from where it resides to (usually a single) `body`-element residing container that is used to create the overlay. The "semantics" of the content has to do with the markup, not with the DOM representation of that content. So you are not breaking any semantic rules by doing this.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context ♦ http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html

Comment: I disagree with you, Jared. The semantics has also to do with the parent-child relationships of the HTML elements. It is not correct, for instance, to have a <main> tag but place the main content outside it. About the idea of copying, it is ok if I don't care about the position of the pop-up (if it is fixed and centered in relation to the screen), but I don't see this as a solution if you want to keep the element positioned in relation to their parent, as is the case (I want the pop-up to be at the bottom of the sidebar).

Comment: Then you're out of luck, dude.

Answer (score 3):

> What's happening now is that the pop-up, which is supposed to be over the black-layer, since their z-index is higher, is actually under it.

As it perfectly well should be. `z-index` is [perfectly well defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html), for example in [this part of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index):

> Each box belongs to one stacking context. Each positioned box in a
>   given stacking context has an integer stack level, which is its
>   position on the z-axis relative other stack levels within the same
>   stacking context. Boxes with greater stack levels are always formatted
>   in front of boxes with lower stack levels. Boxes may have negative
>   stack levels. Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context
>   are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.
>
> The root element forms the root stacking context. Other stacking
>   contexts are generated by any positioned element (including relatively
>   positioned elements) having a computed value of 'z-index' other than
>   'auto'. Stacking contexts are not necessarily related to containing
>   blocks.
>
> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

You are incorrectly assuming z-indexes are shared amongst the entire document, while they are only valid within their own stacking context, which is actually created for every z-indexed element - therefore your `#popup` is the highest element in `#sidebar`, but both are stacked underneath `#black-layer` as it is higher in the root stacking context. Older versions of IE (in quirks mode) actually used the model you are expecting, but that was fixed later on.

So, you'll need to move some elements around. Semantically, that doesn't matter at all since you'll be needing JS anyway to clone/generate the popups in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Niels. I have finally solved the problem by floating the sidebar to the left instead of fixing it in the same place, and adding a position: relative to it. Then the sidebar footer can be properly positioned in relation to the sidebar (with position: absolute) and the z-index property works fine because all the elements are in the same stacking context -- if I understood well.

Comment: Just to complete my answer (though I dodged the initial problem, really, and that's why I'm not posting an answer itself), I found later the problem that if you don't fix the sidebar, then when the main content grows, the sidebar is not going to "follow you" when scrolling. The way I deal with that is by setting the main content to 100% height, and enabling the scroll on overflow-y, so now we are considering the main content as it was the whole window.

Comment: I don't quite understand your second comment. I do realise that the sidebar doesn't appear to grow.