# Hover effect on CSS button

Tags: html, css

I am trying create a hover effect using CSS. Here is the link: http://creativeartbd.com/demo/test.html

Here is the code:

```css
/* GENERAL BUTTON STYLING */
button,
button::after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2em 6em;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  background:red;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

button:hover {
  color: black;
}


/* BUTTON 5 */
.btn-5 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-5::after {
  /*background-color: #f00;*/
  height: 100%;
  left: -35%;
  top: 0;
  transform: skew(50deg);
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 0;
}

.btn-5:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 135%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-5">Button 5</button>
```

now if you run it you can see that there is style when you hover over the button. Now I want to set initial background for this button. So that **IF** I set the background here:

```
button {
   background: orange;
}
```

If I do so then the effect is not showing.

Can you tell me why and how can I solve it?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01jotn2g/)

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your `:after` pseudo-element is actually providing the background, not the button itself.

Comment: yes, its the `:after` providing the background color

Comment: I was trying to create jsfiddle but it's not loading for me.

Comment: To follow up on @cale_b https://jsfiddle.net/01jotn2g/1/

Comment: I was trying to create jsfiddle but it's not loading for me.

Comment: As you have set the pseudo to `z-index:-1` they are _behind_ the button, hence disappear when its background has a color

Comment: @LGSon if I set 1 then text is not showing :(

Comment: I think you're going to need to approach this differently. Use a container element to handle the background effects, and an inner <a> or <button> tag with a transparent background.

Comment: Here is a solution for you: https://jsfiddle.net/vbk6wxfs/ ... it uses a `span` to enable the text to be above the pseudo. Another option would be to use the second (`::after`) pseudo for the text

Comment: And here is the version using both pseudo: https://jsfiddle.net/vbk6wxfs/1/

Comment: let me try it now.

Comment: I decided to close this as a dupe, and the dupe link has another way as well, though think the commented solution(s) I posted here suits you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `z-index:0` to the element to create a stacking context and keep the pseudo element inside. You can then add background

```css
/* GENERAL BUTTON STYLING */
button,
button::after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2em 6em;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  background:orange;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  background:red;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

button:hover {
  color: black;
}


/* BUTTON 5 */
.btn-5 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-5::after {
  /*background-color: #f00;*/
  height: 100%;
  left: -35%;
  top: 0;
  transform: skew(50deg);
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 0;
}

.btn-5:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 135%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-5">Button 5</button>
```

You can also simplify your code like follow:

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2em 6em;
  background:
    linear-gradient(50deg,red 50%,transparent 50.5%),
    orange;
  background-size:250% 100%;
  background-position: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
button:hover {
  color: black;
  background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-5">Button 5</button>
```

Comment: WOW. Simple solution :)

Comment: @Alex It is, though when create tricks with `z-index` can mess up other stuff. The better way is to simply use positioning as I showed in my 2 commented solutions, and allow for the element to layer themselves w/o interfering. As you can see there, no need for `z-index`

Comment: @Alex Here is a few good reads: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/ ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314982/avoid-z-index-working-relative-to-the-parent-element